# Are women allowed to wear Tzitzis and make Berachah?

Tags: halacha, blessing, women, tzitzis

Are women allowed to wear tzitzis, and if they do can they make a bracha?

Comment: Ah, yes. The Tosfos in Yevamos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like most time-bound (day-only), "yes-do" mitzvas, women are not obligated to wear tzitzis.

The opinion of some (Targum Yonasan Devarim 22:5) is that all tzitzis inherently fall under the prohibited category of "mens's garb", thus a woman would not be allowed to wear them.

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe OC 4:49) and others rule otherwise, that they are not inherently prohibited. Though I have heard some (quoted on Rabbi Frand tape) who prefer that they be pink or frilly or otherwise better-demarcated as NOT a man's garment.

If tzitzis are allowed but not obligated for a woman, the next question (as Rav Moshe writes) is one of intent. If this is a woman's way of doing extra mitzvas to serve G-d, fair enough. If it's a political statement, well then that's a different story.

If all these hurdles are cleared, then the question of whether to make a bracha is the time-honored disagreement regarding women making brachas on optional mitzvas: the Ashkenazic opinion as that she should, and the Sephardic opinion that she should not.

Comment: Thank you Shalom which leads to my folow up question why Sefardic women Make Birchas Hatorah if they dont make brachos

Comment: @SimchasTorah, women are obligated to learn "the halacha they need." A Jewish woman's relationship with Torah is not optional like a lulav or tzitzis. Furthermore, the bracha on Torah isn't just a standard acknowledgement of obligation; it's reminding us about the relationship the entire Jewish people have with the Torah.

Comment: The Ashkenazic opinion is that she *can* not *should* https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/117172/759

Answer (score 0):

[R. Jacob Moelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin) stated ([Hilchos Tzitzis U'tefillin # 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14721&st=&pgnum=162&hilite=)) that it is not proper for women to wear tzitzis. When asked why he didn't protest against a woman who did wear tzitzis, he invoked the rule that it is better for them to be [sinning] unintentionally than intentionally.

> אמר מהר"י סג"ל במקום שיש איש יודע לתקן ציציות אל תתקנם האשה ואמר דלא
>   נהירא בעיניו מה שיש נשים מכניסות עצמן לחיוב ציצית ושאלו לו מפני מה
>   אינו מוחה ביד הרבנית מ' ברונא בעירו שהניחה בכל עת טלית קטן והשיב שמא
>   אינה מקשבת לי ועל כה"ג אמר מוטב יהו שוגגין ואל יהו מזידין

[R. Mordechai Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe) wrote ([Levush O.C. 17:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14586&st=&pgnum=22)) that even though women are technically allowed to wear tzitzis, doing so is foolishness and arrogance since women don't generally wear tzitzis, and it might even be a problem of wearing male garments.

> מיהו אם רוצים להתעטף הרשות בידן ויש אומרים אפילו להתעטף ולברך הרשות
>   בידן דאע"פ שלא נצטוו עליהם מכל מקום קצת שכר יש בידם אפילו בקיום מצות
>   עשה שהזמן גרמא וכיון שמקבלות קצת שכר הוו כמצוות ועושות, לפיכך יכולות
>   לברך וצונו ויש אומרים שלא יברכו דכיון שלא נצטוו אינן יכולות לומר וצונו
>   אלא שהרשות בידן להתעטף אבל מכל מקום מיחזי כשטות ויוהרא אם עושות כן
>   דהואיל ואינו אלא חובת גברא מה להם ולמצוה זו הג"ה ועיין לקמן סימן י"ט
>   סעיף א' אע"ג דבשאר מצות עשה שהזמן גרמא כגון סוכה ולולב נהגו שעושין
>   ומברכין מה שנהגו נהגו ומה שלא נהגו לא ינהגו ובציצית לא אשכחן דנהגו רק
>   אחת מני אלף כגון מיכל בת שאול וכיוצא בה לכך לא יתעטפו ועוד נראה לי
>   טעמא דציצית שאני משאר מצות עשה שהזמן גרמא דהואיל וקיי"ל דחובת גברא הוא
>   אם כן לא חייבה התורה בציצית אלא שמלת גבר דבשלמא אי הוה קיי"ל דחובת
>   טלית היא הוה אפשר לומר כל טלית שיש בה ארבע כנפות חייבת בציצית ואפילו
>   שמלת אשה אבל כיון דלא חייבה התורה אלא שמלת איש האיך תתחייב האשה עצמה
>   בדבר שיש בו נדנוד עבירה דהיינוא שמלת גבר ומיכל שאני שהיתה בת מלך ואשת
>   מלך ועיקר מצוה דשמלת גבר לא אסרה תורה אלא כשמלבשת אותה כדי שלא יכירו
>   אותה הכל כדי שתזנה מה שאין שייך כן בבת מלך ואשת מלך שהכל מכירין אותה
>   נ"ל לפיכך אשה שעושה כן ודאי הוא יוהרא יתירה שמראה לכל כלומר שהיא אינה
>   נחשדת נ"ל

Comment: potential nafka minah of the Levush's conclusion about Michal: Ivanka Trump

Comment: @Heshy Huh? Elaborate

Comment: @ezra "and Michal is different because she was the daughter of a king and the wife of a king and the primary mitzva of not wearing men's clothing is when she wears them so other people don't recognize her so that she can behave immorally, which is not relevant for the daughter and wife of kings, since everyone recognizes her."  Ivanka is not the wife of a king, but she's close enough to being the daughter of one, and "everyone recognizes her" is even more true now because of TV, internet, etc.  The Levush's point is a chiddush, so of course, if Ivanka is reading this, CYLOR.

Comment: @ezra The Levush that I cited gives Michal as the example of the 1/1000 women who might wear tzitzis.

Comment: Also interesting that he creates a halachic ramification based on darshening the טעמא דקרא.