# Is a man allowed to say a bracha for a woman if it is a mitzvat aseh shehazman grama and he has already fulfilled his mitzvah?

Tags: blessing, women, shofar

The Rama in Orach Chaim 589:6 states that a man may not say a bracha on the shofar for women who have not yet heard it, if he has already fulfilled his obligation.  Why wouldn't the concept of arvut apply here?  She has opted into a mitzvat aseh shehazman grama, a mitzvah d'oraita. Could a man not say the bracha on netilat lulav or leishev basukkah either if she were performing those mitzvot? Ashkenazi women do say a bracha, so if a woman doesn't know it herself, why couldn't a man with an initial greater obligation say it for her?

Comment: Just because the ashkenazi woman wants to risk the bracha levatala means men should feel a need to risk it for no benefit?

Comment: That's a cynical perspective that I haven't seen raised by a rishon or acharon.  Ashkenazi women universally have the custom of saying a bracha when they chose to do a MASh''G.  No reason to think they would be making a bracha levatala.

Comment: The Rama below says explicitly that while ashkenazim don't protest women saying the blessings, they aren't excited about it since it would be better if the women avoided it. That's about as authoritative an Ashkenazi Rabbi as you can imagine

Answer (score 2):

The Rema explains in [Darchei Moshe](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beit_Yosef%2C_Orach_Chaim.589.5.1?lang=bi&p2=Darchei_Moshe%2C_Orach_Chaim.589.2.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en):

> וכן מהרי"ל פסק כדברי ראבי"ה והרא"ש. וכתב דאין לתקוע לנשים עד אחר שתקעו בצבור ולא קודם לכן, מיהו אם היא יולדת או חולה ואינה יכולה להמתין יתקע לה מיד. וכתב עוד דהאשה תברך לעצמה ואם לא יכולה לברך יברך התוקע בשבילה. ול"נ כדברי ב"י דאם תוקעין לה אחר שיצא לא יברך לה התוקע, דאע"ג דאין מוחין לנשים המברכות על מצות עשה, מ"מ מוטב שלא לברך כמ"ש לעיל סי' י"ז, אבל לברך אחר בשבילה נראה דאסור, דהרי אמרו כל הברכות כולן אע"פ שיצא מוציא חוץ מברכת הלחם והיין וה"ה לכל ברכת הנהנין שאם יצא אינו מוציא הואיל ואינו מחוייב בדבר אסור לברך לחבירו בשבילו, וכ"ש בברכות אלו שהנשים בעצמן עדיף שלא לברך אלא שאין מוחין בידן שאין לאחר לברך בשבילן. כן נ"ל:

In short, the Maharil writes that if the woman can not say the beracha herself, the (man) blowing for her should make the beracha for her; but the Rema himself disagrees, since the one saying the beracha is not obligated in that beracha, and even the woman is just allowed to say the beracha even though it is not preferable.

Comment: Your English summary says the rule but not the reason for it, which is what the question seeks.